# Iterate over arbitrary-length tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable, scalaquery

I just started with Scala and ran into a problem:

Scala has the Types `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, …, `Tuple22`. Scalaquery returns tuples when iterating over queries.

I have now a given class (ZK’s `ListitemRenderer`), which accepts `Object`s and populates gui lists with rows, each consisting of some cells. But `ListitemRenderer` isn’t generic. So my problem is that i have an `Object` “data”, which really is a tuple of arbitrary length, which i have to iterate over to create the cells (simply with `data._1.toString`, …).

Since <del>there is no</del> **I didn’t know the** supertype to `Tuple1-22`, i <del>can’t</del> **couldn’t** just do `data.asInstanceOf[Tuple].productIterator foreach {…}`

What can i do?

---

Below Answer told me that there is indeed a Trait to all Tuples – `Product` – providing the desired `foreach` function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All `TupleX` classes inherit from `Product`, which defines `def productIterator : Iterator[Any]`. You can call it to iterates through all elements of any tuple.

For example:

```
def toStringSeq(tuple: Product) = tuple.productIterator.map(_.toString).toIndexedSeq
```

Comment: so i do `data.asInstanceOf[Product].productIterator foreach {…}`?

Comment: @flying sheep: That should do the trick, but you could type the `data` argument of your function as a `Product` instead of `Any` or `AnyRef` (I guess you mean that when you say `Object`). That would save you the cast.

Comment: as said in the question: the function i’m in implements a function from a non-generic interface, so i can’t change the typing and have to cast, except scala has a way to monkeypatch the the interface to be generic.